# Combining two lists in python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Suppose I have two lists of any, but equal length, for example:

```
['a','b','c','d']
['r','t','y','h']
```

For these two lists, I would want output to be:

```
'ar', 'bt', 'cy', 'dh'
```

Basically, the first element of the first list to the first element of the second list and so on.  How would I do that?  And note, that the lists can be of any length, not just what the example shows, but the length of the first list is equal to the length of the second list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists to combine them, then [`join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) each pair of strings into a single string:

```
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> list2 = ['r','t','y','h']
>>> [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(list1, list2)]
['ar', 'bt', 'cy', 'dh']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `zip` to do the job:

```
>>> l1=['a','b','c','d']
>>> l2=['r','t','y','h']
>>> map(lambda(x,y): x+y, zip(l1,l2))
['ar', 'bt', 'cy', 'dh']
```

What `zip` does is it creates a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each list.  Then you can transform each tuple into a string by concatenation (using `lambda(x,y): x+y`).

Comment: Unfortunately that syntax will no longer work in Python 3 -- `lambda (x,y): x+y`, I mean.

Comment: A list comprehension is generally considered to be more Pythonic than `map` over a `lambda`. In addition to the syntax problem, you'd also need to wrap this in a call to `list` on Python 3 because `map` is lazy. My solution also has the advantage that it expands to handle any number of input lists because it uses `join`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a functional approach you can use `map` and `operator.add`

```
import operator
map(operator.add,['a','b','c','d'], ['r','t','y','h'])
>>>['ar', 'bt', 'cy', 'dh']
```

No need for `lambdas` nor list comprehension to do the concatenation.

**NOTE:** For those who say is not Python 3, this dump could make you change your mind:

```
Python 3.1.3 (r313:86834, Nov 28 2010, 10:01:07)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import operator
>>> list(map(operator.add, ['a','b'],['r','t']))
['ar', 'bt']
```

Comment: Thats not Python3 though :p

Comment: Or use `''.join` if you want to generalize. Also, list comprehensions are functional.

Comment: @agf I don't see how `''.join` can generalize it more than `operator.add`, the latter works for whatever input. `join` only does it with string lists.

Comment: @PauloBu `add` only takes two input lists, `''.join` takes any number of input lists.

Comment: @agf there you made your point :) Anyways, I was just trying to give another option to the OP following the title of the question. _combining two lists_.

Comment: @PauloBu, yes. I was referring to the fact that `map` doesn't return a list in Python3

Answer (score 1):

The above answer seems to be valid also for Python 2.7. In addition, you can just use zip and an inline adder (lambda):

## 1:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']

list2 = ['r','t','y','h']

add = lambda pair:pair[0]+pair[1]

print [add(pair) for pair in zip(list1, list2)]
```

## 2:

or just in one line:

```
print map(lambda pair:pair[0]+pair[1],[pair for pair in zip(list1,list2)])
```

## 3:

`map()` allows mapping multiple arguments, which yields a short solution:

```
print map(lambda x,y:x+y, list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more ways to do it

```
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> list2 = ['r','t','y','h']

>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
['ar', 'bt', 'cy', 'dh']

>>> it = iter(list2)
>>> [x + next(it) for x in list1]
['ar', 'bt', 'cy', 'dh']
```